# How to inherit props from parent route with vue-router

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-router4

I have the following router configuration and would like that the `id` of the `main.parent` route is converted to an integer and then passed into the child components (given `props: true`) for all child components.

```
{
  path: '/',
  component: GrandparentComponent,
  name: 'main',
  children: [{
    path: ':id',
    component: ParentComponent,
    name: 'main.parent',
    props: route => {
      return {
        // parse URL id to int
        id: parseInt(route.params.id, 10)
      };
    },

    children: [{
      path: 'details',
      name: 'main.parent.child',
      component: ChildComponent,
      props: true,
      children: [{
        ...
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

However, it seems as if the [route function](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode) is only really called once (when evaluating `/:id`) and not when `/:id/details` is evaluated. The relevant code in vue-router seems to confirm this.

```
            const route = routeToDisplay.value;
            const matchedRoute = matchedRouteRef.value;
            const ViewComponent = matchedRoute && matchedRoute.components[props.name];
            // we need the value at the time we render because when we unmount, we
            // navigated to a different location so the value is different
            const currentName = props.name;
            if (!ViewComponent) {
                return normalizeSlot(slots.default, { Component: ViewComponent, route });
            }
            // props from route configuration
            const routePropsOption = matchedRoute.props[props.name];
            const routeProps = routePropsOption
                ? routePropsOption === true
                    ? route.params
                    : typeof routePropsOption === 'function'
                        ? routePropsOption(route)
                        : routePropsOption
                : null;
            ...
            const component = h(ViewComponent, assign({}, routeProps, attrs, {
                onVnodeUnmounted,
                ref: viewRef,
            }));
            ...
```

I wonder if anyone tried to solve the same problem and what they came up with a solution. Ideally, I'd like to avoid duplicating the props function for every child route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such feature in Vue Router for passing props to child routes that way.

Instead, you could use [`provide`/`inject`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html) to effectively do this. The parent would `provide` the `id` property, and any descendant could `inject` it:

1. In `ParentComponent.vue`, use [`toRefs()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#torefs) on `props` to get a reactive `ref` to the `id` prop.
2. Use [`provide()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#provide-inject) to provide that `id` to any children (including child routes).
3. Apply a [`key`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/special-attributes.html#key) on `<router-view>` to ensure the view is re-rendered based on  the unique `id`.
4. In `ChildComponent.vue`, use the `inject` prop to inject the `id` from step 2.

```html
// ParentComponent.vue
<script>
/* Composition API */
import { provide, toRefs } from 'vue'

export default {
  props: ['id'],
  setup(props) {
    const { id } = toRefs(props)
    provide('id', id)
  },
}

/* Options API */
import { toRefs } from 'vue'

export default {
  props: ['id'],
  provide() {
    const { id } = toRefs(this.$props)
    return { id }
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <router-view :key="id" />
</template>
```

```html
// ChildComponent.vue
<script>
export default {
  inject: ['id'],
}
</script>

<template>
  <h2>Detail {{ id }}</h2>
</template>
```

[Composition API demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-inject-reactive-props-in-child-routes?file=src/components/ParentComponent.vue)

[Options API demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-inject-reactive-props-in-child-routes-2ckfvm?file=src/components/ParentComponent.vue)

Comment: No, it's not necessary to call `provide` again. The parent's `provide` makes `id` available to *all* descendants, no matter how deep in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

##### TL;DR [See working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-enfxfp?file=src%2Frouter.js&terminal=dev)

---

*I don't clearly understand what you are asking, but here is my understanding of your questions:*

1. Is the route function called only once on the parent component and not on the children?
2. How to not repeat props function code for every child route
3. How to inherit props from parent component(s)

### 1: Nope, the route function will be called on each child route.

### 2: Abstract the function code

Instead of copy-pasting or repeating the function code, you can create a function and use that:

```
const parseUrlIdtoInt = (route) => ({ id: parseInt(route.params.id, 10) });

// ...
{
  path: '...'
  props: parseUrlIdtoInt,
  children: [
    {
      path: '...',
      props: parseUrlIdtoInt 
    }
  ] 
}
//...
```

### 3: Vue router passes down props

If the `props` property is specified in the router configuration, then Vue Router automatically passes down the props.

*- With props option we enable passing props to the component*
*- With function props we control how and what prop to pass*

```js
// Router configuration
{
  path: '...',
  name: '...',
  props: true // or a function 
  // ...
}
```

### Your Solution

So in order to access `id` prop in your `ChildComponent` you can define props and use it:

*Composition API*

```html
<script setup>
defineProps({ id: Number });
</script>
```

*Options API*

```html
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    id: Number,
  },
});
</script>
```

### Other non-so-recommended solutions

- If you don't want to define props, you can access the id with `$attrs.id` in the template.
- Or you can use `useRoute()` function from Vue Router and access params:

```html
<script setup>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

const route = useRoute()
</script>

<template>
 {{ route.params.id }}
</template>
```